# How to perform rolling sum from another category

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

I'm trying to perform some calculation to retrieve the rolling total of a category between two occurrences of another category.

I'm conscious it's not easy to describe by words.

So, here is the example of the input dataframe and the expected output

Input:

```
Date       Category  Value
2012-01-04        A     10
2012-01-06        A     20
2012-02-15        B    -10
2012-04-29        A      5
2012-04-30        A     70
2012-10-15        A     15
2012-10-16        B    -30
2012-11-19        B    -50
```

Expected output:
Only the rows B but mentioning the rolling total of A since the previous occurrence of B

```
Date       Category  Value  Total_A_since_previous_B
2012-02-15        B    -10                        30
2012-10-16        B    -30                        90
2012-11-19        B    -50                         0
```

I've tried several things without success.

Can you help me to understand how to do that?

Comment: What are the several things you've tried? What were the problems with them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create groups for each occurence of B,sum the Values and then assign it as a new column to the filtered df.

```
(
    pd.Series(np.where(df.Category.eq('B'), df.index, np.nan)).bfill()
    .pipe(lambda x: df.groupby(x).Value.apply(lambda x: x[:-1].sum()))
    .pipe(lambda x: df[df.Category=='B'].assign(Total_A_since_previous_B=x))
)

    Date        Category    Value   Total_A_since_previous_B
2   2012-02-15  B           -10     30
6   2012-10-16  B           -30     90
7   2012-11-19  B           -50     0
```

Comment: It wasn't so simple, so I will have a look in detail to learn more :)
one additional question, how can I include a first column Product to group the results of each product ?

Comment: Oh sorry, it works as well.!!! so no issue. thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`GroupBy.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html):

```
blocks = df.Category.shift().eq('B').cumsum()
new_df = (df.groupby(blocks)
            .agg(Date= ('Date','last'),
                 Category = ('Category','last'),
                 Value = ('Value','last'),
                 Total_A_since_previous_B = ('Value','sum')
                )
             .assign(Total_A_since_previous_B = lambda x: x.Total_A_since_previous_B
                                                           .sub(x.Value))
             .reset_index(drop=True))

print(new_df)
         Date Category  Value  Total_A_since_previous_B
0  2012-02-15        B    -10                        30
1  2012-10-16        B    -30                        90
2  2012-11-19        B    -50                         0
```

Comment: Your solution produces 4 rows instead of 3.

Comment: check now @MykolaZotko

Comment: Thanks also for your solution.